# What does the term in "the playing fields" as used in the Bhagadavida Gita really mean?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, maya, prakruti

There is a verse in the Bhagadavida Gita that refers to the earth world realm and it's 3rd dimensional limitations emplaced there as "the playing fields".  I have a few ideas as-to-what what this may really mean, but would like to know what others say and what the general overall consensus is.

Comment: Which verse of Bhagavad Gita? [Edit](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/22547/edit) the question to include the verse which you're referring.

Comment: Probably you are talking about *Kshetra* (field) & *Kshetragna* (knower, not player). It's [13th chapter's beginning](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kshetrajna). But nothing to do with 3D. It says that, the body which one relates to oneself is nothing but a field which is not under control. The one who resides inside as a witness, is the knower/enjoyer of the field. It's also referred as soul popularly.